# SheetJS, excel to mysql database

Tags: php, javascript

Estou a tentar extrair de um excel todos os dados para inserir numa tabela de mysql. Correndo o exemplo dado no github, retorna-me um erro, require is not define.

https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/blob/master/demos/database/MySQLTest.js

Existe alguma forma mais correta de o fazer?